# Tensorflow: ios compiling errors ( duplicate symbols)

Tags: c++, ios, tensorflow

I was compiling tensorflow for ios, and was following the instructions at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile[1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile).

I was able to pass the first two steps:

```
sh tensorflow/contrib/makefile/download_dependencies.sh



sh tensorflow/contrib/makefile/compile_ios_protobuf.sh
```

However, I got duplicate symbol errors? when I ran

```
make -f tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile \
 TARGET=IOS \
 IOS_ARCH=ARM64
```

Anyone can help? thanks

Here are the errors:

```
~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a -arch arm64 
-miphoneos-version-min=9.2 -framework Accelerate -Xlinker -S -Xlinker -x -Xlinker -dead_strip -all_load 
L ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf_ios/lib -lz -lstdc++ -lprotobuf -lz -lm

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDef10SharedDtorEv in:
 ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)


duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDef10SharedCtorEv in:
~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)


duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDef5ClearEv in:
 ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow72protobuf_ShutdownFile_tensorflow_2fcore_2fframework_2fnode_5fdef_2eprotoEv in:
~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)


duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow70protobuf_AssignDesc_tensorflow_2fcore_2fframework_2fnode_5fdef_2eprotoEv 
in: ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)


duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow67protobuf_AddDesc_tensorflow_2fcore_2fframework_2fnode_5fdef_2eprotoEv in:
 ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)


duplicate symbol __ZNK10tensorflow7NodeDef8ByteSizeEv in:
 ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDef16default_instanceEv in:  
~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDef21InitAsDefaultInstanceEv in:
 ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZNK10tensorflow7NodeDef13IsInitializedEv in:  
~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZNK10tensorflow7NodeDef11GetMetadataEv in:
 ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDefD2Ev in:
 ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDefC2Ev in:  
~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDefD1Ev in: 
 ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDefC1Ev in:  
~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDefD0Ev in:  
~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZNK10tensorflow7NodeDef13SetCachedSizeEi in: 
 ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZNK10tensorflow7NodeDef39InternalSerializeWithCachedSizesToArrayEbPh in:
  ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDef8CopyFromERKS0_ in:   
 ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDef9MergeFromERKS0_ in:    
~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDefC2ERKS0_ in:
    ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDefC1ERKS0_ in:
    ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZNK10tensorflow7NodeDef24SerializeWithCachedSizesEPN6google8protobuf2io17CodedOutputStreamE in:
    ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDef27MergePartialFromCodedStreamEPN6google8protobuf2io16CodedInputStreamE in:
 ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZTVN10tensorflow7NodeDefE in:    
~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZTSN10tensorflow7NodeDefE in:  
~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZTIN10tensorflow7NodeDefE in:
    ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDef8CopyFromERKN6google8protobuf7MessageE in:
    ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDef9MergeFromERKN6google8protobuf7MessageE in:
    ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZNK10tensorflow7NodeDef3NewEPN6google8protobuf5ArenaE in:
    ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDefC2EPN6google8protobuf5ArenaE in:
    ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDefC1EPN6google8protobuf5ArenaE in:
    ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow81static_descriptor_initializer_tensorflow_2fcore_2fframework_2fnode_5fdef_2eproto_E in:
    ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

duplicate symbol __ZN10tensorflow7NodeDef17default_instance_E in:
    ~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/ios_ARM64/libtensorflow-core.a(node_def.pb.o)

ld: 44 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [~/Documents/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/bin/ios_ARM64/benchmark] Error 1
```

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: @bub  thanks,  reformatted

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have more than one,

```
libtensorflow-core.a in your project.
```

So try to remove it and than make it again.

There are some duplicate file or method or variables in your project. So try to search them and remove them.

Comment: Thanks,  it's a bit weird. I checkouted the lastest commit in tensorflow repo: 4c49dbebef05442c7e72d6129a30574fcd13f0e1. Somehow, the compiling errors were gone.

Comment: Welcome bro. @H. Mao

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing, the `HEAD` of TensorFlow does not build well for iOS. It'd help if such transient question was closed, so here are two generic mechanisms (if I missed a related question to link to, please help!):

- If you are checking out the bleeding edge of any kind of repository (typically the `HEAD` on `master` if you are using Git), expect to break. Release tags are often way more stable, and should build well, to the cost of lacking the latest changes. For example, `git tag` lists up tags, and there usually are `vX.Y.Z` patterns to pick from.
- If you have to re-build from source, it is often better---not always needed---to clean the current build first. Cleaning takes time, so you can be optimistic and build directly, then clean/build if any problem shows up. Typically, commands look like `make -f tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile clean`.

Also, TensorFlow's official build system relies on Bazel, and the `make` build system is most of the time lagging behind: All platforms that rely on `make` have higher risk to break at `HEAD` (again, that is not always true). Note by the way that the `make` build system is in the `tensorflow/contrib` directory, which is explicitly set aside.